# What can cause PCIe graphics cards to randomly fail during boot?

Tags: graphics-card, diagnostic, sli

I have a system that's currently driving me crazy, and I'm hoping someone out here on StackExchange will be able to point out something I'm doing wrong.

The computer is home-built and consists of:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 4790K (stock @ 4GHz)
- MB: Gigabyte GA-Z97X-Gaming G1 WIFI-BK
- RAM: G.skill Trident X F3-2400C10Q-32GTX (8GBx4 matched kit)
- GFX: 2x Gigabyte GV-N980G1 GAMING-4GD GTX 980 (SLI)
- PWR: Corsair HX1000i
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Every time I power on the machine, it's a coin-toss whether or not the graphics cards will come online. If I'm lucky, the cards power up and I get a display signal (via DP-out) to my main monitor. When this happens, the machine appears to operate correctly until power cycled, although its performance is well below where it should be for the hardware (3DMark Fire Strike Extreme score of roughly 8000, compared to Futuremark's listed 10100 for a reference system with identical CPU and graphics cards).

If I'm unlucky, the machine boots and video comes online with the integrated Intel graphics (which I have routed to a second monitor). Device manager does not detect the NVIDIA cards at all. They don't show up as "unknown device", they don't show up as "failed startup" -- they're just missing completely.

Following usual procedure for these sorts of situations, I've removed and reseated the motherboard, cards, power supply and all power connections. I've checked to make sure that there are no loose conductors that could possibly be causing shorts. I've checked the CPU and GPU temperatures to make sure that they're running well within thermal limits under load (approximately 65C for GPUs and 55C for CPU).

I'm completely baffled by this. Any suggestions (no matter how obvious) would be much appreciated.

Updated:

At the request of Journeyman Geek in the comments, I've run tests on the machine with each graphics card installed individually. This does seem to solve the problem: I've booted the system about a dozen times with each card and it hasn't failed to come up yet. In addition, 3DMark confirms that the cards are individually performing at average for this hardware configuration with a single GPU.

So this problem seems to be specifically related to using the two cards in an SLI configuration.

I'm currently doing some more tests with the two cards in a different PCIe slot configuration (1&2 instead of 1&3) to see if maybe I've got a bad slot on the board.

Update 2:

Slot 1&2 configuration worked fine and benched 9600 on 3DMark Fire Strike Extreme. (Low, but that's expected with two double-wide cards side by side; they're going to overheat and thermally throttle each other without a heavy-duty liquid or phase change system in place.)

After running a few tests in this configuration, I put the cards back in 1&3. Now everything is working correctly across another dozen boots. System now benches 10800 on FSE.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is possibly different this time as opposed to the half dozen times I've reseated the cards before. Will keep running this configuration for a couple of days and close out my question as "caused by goblins" if I can't reproduce the error condition again.

Comment: I'd wonder if you have enough power, but I'd assume a quality 1KW supply should be enough. Does a single card work reliably? Also, you're specifically talking about video cards, there's other PCIe cards around :)

Comment: In theory the max TDP of the GPUs is 165W each, and the CPU is 88W. (I didn't mention in the question, but there's an SSD and two HHDDs in the system as well as a Blu-ray burner, none of which should be consuming a lot of power.) By any reasonable measure a 1KW PSU should vastly exceed the system's power requirements even if it was assumed to be operating at 60% efficiency.

Comment: Yeah, I might have a few more theories but testing with a single graphics card is where I'd start. You probably should have enough power  for what you're doing which makes this a little more curious.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Updated question with results of single-card tests.

Comment: Well, I'm baffled. Tempted to post an answer, but I have no idea why it works now. I guess something somewhere was loose, and the single card test ensured you got it right ;)

Comment: Do you have the latest bios installed? Sounds like a bios issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a beefy gaming computer, but I would still suspect the power supply first — confirm that your power supply meets or exceeds the recommended wattage on the 12V rails then compare that to what the specs on the 980's must meet.

You mentioned Windows 8.1, so I would also say look to at your logs and see if you can glean any more information as to why your drivers are not showing up.

I ran into this issue with two 980's in January but did not bother investigating further because I upgraded to an ASUS motherboard and an older Thermaltake power supply and the problem went away.